# Why does Chrome sometimes download a website instead of showing it?

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

Chrome sometimes crashes without giving any error code or report. Just like that.

Sometimes it's very frequent. It won't even show the  dialogue asking me to restart. I have to run it again and thn I have to restore the tabs. As soon as I start Chrome again, maybe after a few seconds it will crash and then again and so on.

My second problem is that it downloads unncessary files. Sometimes when I try to visit `cnet.com` instead of opening the site it just downloads some file. Sometimes it will ask me whether to save or discard `Somefilename.html`. For other sites it will download `like.php` or piclist or index.

If i go to [this answers.yahoo.com thread](http://in.answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20091129185819AAvfsGT) it will download `index`.

Comment: Have you checked other browsers to see if it's only a problem in Chrome?  If so and the problem exists elsewhere as well, you may have a virus.  Try on FF or IE and see if the same thing happens.

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/359844/prompt-to-download-webpage-instead-of-open

Comment: this is not happening with other browsers. this is the case whwn iam using chrome..

Answer (score 5):

It does this because Alt is pressed. Press Alt again to get out of that mode.

Answer (score 0):

(Please don't ask two questions together.)

Your first question is probably caused by bugs and you should update. (It could also be a local virus or remote exploit attempt, but I haven't seen many targeting Chrome.)

As of your second question, it's caused by the server sending the wrong content type (octet-stream as opposed to html). However, it is unlikely the websites you refered to have this kind of problem, so there is probably something sitting between your browser and the website modifying the response. If in doubt, set chrome to use no proxy and run a thorough virus scan of your computer. If you're on a hostile network environment (e.g. public Wifi, poorly-managed company network, etc.), you might want to use HTTPS connection for everything or use VPN.